# Too many open file error, java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, file

In my program I have loop that scans a bunch of files and reads their content. The problem happened over the iteration of about 1500 files and can't seem to be reproduced (or understood (by me))

The problem:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /path/to/file//myFile (Too many open files)
```

Exception points to this method:

```
private static String readFileAsRawString(File f) throws IOException {

    FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(f); // <------------Stacktrace
    try{
      FileChannel fc = stream.getChannel();
      MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());

      return Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString();
    } finally {
        stream.close();
    }
}
```

I ran this method over 20,000 files in QA and it seems to have no problems.

Do you see anything wrong with code i pasted above that would cause this issue?

Comment: Did you use the same OS in both environments (QA and the one which failed?)

Comment: No. Production system is Linux, my tests ran on a MAC

Comment: Returning the data before closing the file. Probably that is causing the problem. Try placing return after finally block.

Comment: Finally is called before the return, i believe

Comment: What's outside this?  You may be opening directories and not closing them.

Comment: (Remember, for an error of this sort the exception does not necessarily identify the "guilty party".)

Comment: I'd try closing the `FileChannel`s as well - it might be getting the channel for a file creates a new file handle.

Comment: Also, does your OS provide a way to tell what files a process has open? I know some task manager apps on Windows (like the SysInternals one) can do that, so it might be worth seeing exactly what is open to pinpoint the cause.

Comment: @millimoose, Yes, i made that change as well, cleaned up methods oveall too. Will test on Monday

Comment: The lsof command lists open files ref https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/lsof.8.html

Comment: Check what the `maxfiles` (Mac) and `ulimit` (Linux) values are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mapping is suspect. A `MappedByteBuffer` can outlive its `FileChannel`, and is valid until it is garbage collected. You might not have enough garbage to run the GC, but perhaps on a particular platform file handles are retained by unreferenced buffers.

---

Unless explicit garbage collection is disabled (`-XX:-DisableExplicitGC`), you should be able to test for this by catching the exception, calling `System.gc()`, and trying again. If it works on the second try, that's your problem. However, calling `System.gc()` as a permanent fix is a bad idea. The solution that will perform best overall will take some profiling on the target platform.

Comment: What concerns me is my inability to reproduce the problem on my machine (MAC), i will certainly verify how this behaves in Prod (Linux) on Monday.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use MappedByteBuffer for this trivial task. There is no well-defined time at which they are released. Just open the file, read it, close it.

Comment: Apache's `FileUtils.readFileToString(f);` seems like less code and cleaner solution. Will test on Monday.

Answer (score -1):

I think you open too many files to fast, try to add a wait() to test this.
Then add a static counter that keeps tracks of opens files and if many files are already open, add a wait mechanism...

Comment: Why? What does speed have to do with it, and why would a wait help? Unexplained guesswork is not an answer. -1.